# Change setInveral/Timeout speed dynamically with range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder if it's possible to change setInterval or setTimeout speed dynamically with html5 range input? If so how do I do that? I've tried to save value from input to a variable and then set the variable as an Interval/Timeout time but It didn't work and the Interval/Timeout worked full speed on change.
Can anyone give me some examples, please? :)

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var b = newValue;
  delay = b;
  setInterval(function(){ 
  console.log("Hi")
  }, delay);
  

}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

```html
<input name="1" type="range" min="1000" max="7000" step="10" value="0">
```

Comment: It's absolutely possible. Just use `document.getElementById().value` to pass through the value to use. If that isn't working for you, you'll need to update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've tried that way, but without success. https://codepen.io/Hatchling/pen/eRaELE

Comment: put the code you tried in the question

Comment: stackoverflow has the same features you are using on codepen. click the snipplet button on the toolbar when you edit your question.

Comment: The `input` event is going to fire multiple times for the range input as it is slid, so when you think you are only setting 1 interval/timeout you are setting multiple. Add a console.log to the callback and you will see it fire multiple times as you slide it.

Comment: Any way I can fix that? I'm not so faimiliar with js so far. :/ btw I've edited my Question so you can see the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input event is going to fire multiple times for the range input as it is slid, so when you think you are only setting 1 interval/timeout you are setting multiple. This gives the impression that your timer is running at fullspeed (which I assume you mean as if it was set to 0 delay).

What you can do to counter act that is save the timer id that is returned from setTimeout/Interval. Then immediately clear it at the beginning of the callback to make sure any previous timers are no longer running.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var timerId = null;

var rangeValue = function(){
  clearInterval(timerId);
  var delay = elem.value;
  timerId = setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("Hi")
  }, delay);
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

```html
<input name="1" type="range" min="1000" max="7000" step="10" value="0">
```

Comment: Well, so simple and so hard for me at the same time tho. Thank you for your help I  appreciate it.

Comment: I have one more question, how do I get the value of slider without moving it? I mean I have setTimeout which generally activate him self when some actions is done. In my case when the player moves 1 step from me, it calls the function but it has timeout on fight function (Generally it's a script that auto attack player when a player is 1 step from my hero.) I applied this script on the Timeout I have there, but it only worked when I moved the slider and player were 1 step from my hero.

Comment: Can anyone help? :)

Comment: just do `elem.value` to get the value of the slider... if you want to get the value of the slider some where other than your timer callback, just define `elem` in a higher scope so you can use it where needed

Comment: It's kinda more complicated because of the elem.value returns value of the slider. But I wanna do some counting on that variable such as picking a random number between for example 300 and my slider value which will be for example min 700 to max 1200. So it will pick random number between 300 and 700/1220  and that number will be mine setTimeout delay. But as I said before, there is a problem because if I wanna do it that way I explained above it will "update" the variable after counting just when I move the slider.

Comment: Which sucks. I am not so familiar with js so far, still learning, but I actually need to do it, that's the reason why I'm asking the question here. : /

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two different things.  First you need to store the current interval so you can clear it when a new one is set.  Also you should add a timeout when the slider is changed so that you're not setting the interval at every value along the path.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
var slideInput;
var currentInterval;

var rangeValue = function(){
  if (currentInterval) {
    clearInterval(currentInterval);
  }
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var b = newValue;
  delay = b;
  currentInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
  console.log("Hi")
  }, delay);
  

}

elem.addEventListener("input", function()
{
  if (slideInput) {
    clearTimeout(slideInput);
  }
  
  slideInput = setTimeout(rangeValue, 250);
});
```

```html
<input name="1" type="range" min="1000" max="7000" step="10" value="0">
```